# Problems with Jquery 1.8 in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am investigating a little problem on [it-minds.dk](http://www.it-minds.dk/) where the overlay box, that appears when clicking one of the links, appears and disappears immediatly after.

As there were no further info on when, how or why the problem occured, I had to start from scratch with various browsers, safety sittings and what not. To no avail unfortunately.

Though, i noticed that the site was running with Jquery 1.6.3 and i thought that this might be the issue so i decided to update it to 1.8.0.

The site still worked fine after the update in all browsers but Google Chrome.

In Google Chrome the overlay would not trigger after the update. and i have no clue why.

In a feeble attempt to improve the Jquery some without giving up on Chrome users, i tested Jquery 1.7.2 and it made Chrome work again and hopefully prevent the general overlay open/close problem.

Though, my question is: 
 1. Anyone able to reproduce the situation where clicking a link makes the overlay appear/disappear within the blink of an eye?
 2. Anyone able to explain to my why Chrome stops working when using Jquery 1.8.0 on this site?

Thanks in advance - Rasmus

Comment: Did you at least hit F12 and check the console for errors before asking ?

Comment: You have to post some relevant html/script/css or even a fiddle on jsFiddle.net demonstrating the issue. If you can't replicate it in a fiddle with your code, how are we to reproduce it without code or any debugging results from your side? So far, as it stands, the issue sounds to localised.

Comment: @Adeneo - I did at least check the console and it did not report anything unusual.

Comment: @François Wahl - It would require me to repost the entire site to be able show you the problem. My thoughts were if anyone interessed in helping, they could insert the 1.8.0 Jquery script through a console add-on or what not. Unfortunaly as this is a live site i am not able to leave the "faulty" jquery version on for you fellas to test out.